# Can angular4 route to a file with .html extsion?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

such as :

```
{path: 'overview.html', component: OverviewComponent},
```

Is it valid? Because I want to route to a local html file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, because `overview.html` is the path name you chose and the dot is a valid character in path names. I tried it, and tried `overview$html` and `overview.html....` (yes, with four dots) and they all work, blindly. That said, you shouldn't not go for such naming! The actual `html` template file is loaded when the path (in your case, `overview.html`) resolves to a proper component (`OverviewComponent`) which has a `selector` that points to the proper `html` file. This is probably what you intended in the first place. So, you could (should) swap `overview.html` for just `overview` or even `ov` and it should work.

Comment: actually, I'd like to route to a individual html file which doesn't belong to any component. What directory should I put the file into?

Comment: Got you. I am not sure you could use the Angular router in that way. I know you could discard the component and redirect to some paths, but those paths should eventually resolve to some component template.